# Oracle 11g ado connection strings for ODBC (not OLEDB) using excel VBA 64 bit (DSN Less and tnsnames)

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, oracle11g, adodb

Please help.  I have researched this for hours.  I get some parts to work but not others.

What I am trying to do is write all the connection strings in excel VBA to connect to Oracle 11g database.  I don't want to set up the User DSN in ODBC Administrator and I don't want to have to maintain a tnsnames.ora file.

I can get this to work for OLEDB connection strings but I believe this is no longer supported by Oracle so I want to use the Oracle ODBC Driver commands only.

This is what I have got to work (which requires a tnsnames.ora file)

`DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=MyTNSnamesALias;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx`

I have tried this also but I get a TNS Protocol error

```
DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};
Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=xxxx)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx
```

Other useful information might be that i get my connections to work just fine when I use the DSN name as per the ODBC Administrator.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to do TNSPING to the database? Are all the components (Excel, Oracle ODBC Driver) on 64 bit (or all on 32 bit)?

Answer (score 3):

OLEDB Provider from Oracle (`Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle`) is still supported, just the provider from Microsoft (`Provider=msdaora`) is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Microsoft recommends to use the Oracle provider.

Microsoft provider `msdaora` does even not exist for 64 Bit.

I think your connection string for Oracle ODBC must be this (without the line breaks):

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};
   DBQ=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));
   Pwd=xxxx;
   Uid=xxxx
```

Note, for the Oracle driver you must use `DBQ` instead of `Server`.

`Server` is the attribute for the Microsoft ODBC driver (e.g. `Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}`)

Comment: This now works.  I didn't need the entire tnsnames entry. Basically the code was amended to 

con.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=host name:port number/SID;UID=XXXXX;PWD=XXXX"

I was able to connect with no tnsnames.ora entry required or any DSN setup in ODBC Administrator.

Also, thanks for the clarification around OLD DB.  My mistake so I have read so much about using OLE v ODBC and I really don't know why they have 2 different ways to connect.  Which is better in everyone's opinion?

Comment: ODBC is more generic (you have ODBC driver even for CSV files),thus you may have some limitations when you work with Oracle. You should use it when you have to work with a various number of different data sources. OLE DB is more specific to RDBMS, I think OLE DB brings more gain (at least on paper, no idea about the practical differences) when you work with Oracle DB.

Answer (score 3):

There are no possibility to connect using `Oracle ODBC driver` without TNS alias already configured in `tnsnames.ora` file.

All configuration steps mentioned in `Oracle ODBC Driver` documentation requires it:

1. [Connecting to DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1155)
2. [Configuring theDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#BABBCBHH)
3. [Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration Dialog Box](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#BABEFEHG)

Also in [documentation for SQLDriverConnect implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1188) `DBQ` parameter noted as required, and passing a name of TNS alias in this parameter is only method to specify server to connect to.
Because it's a common API function used by all clients of Oracle ODBC Driver, there are no possibility that some other interface (COM-object, configuration dialog or something else) may accept different parameters for connection.

There are no such possibility in [Oracle Objects for OLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28378/intro.htm) too.

---

I can't find anything about cancelling of `Oracle Provider for OLEDB` support.
It has been released as a part of latest version of ODAC: ["ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63382/toc.htm) and this release is a [top news topic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)  at related section of Oracle site at the moment.
There are [some improvements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63382/release_changes.htm#OLEDB259) in latest versions and [support for usage from .NET applications](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63382/using.htm#OLEDB0002).

Also, it works (at least for me):

```
Const hostName = "server_host"
Const portNo = "1521"
Const srvSID = "ORASERVERSID"
Const usrID = "login"
Const usrPwd = "password"

Sub con_Oracle_OLEDB()

  strDriver = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;"
  strParams = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=MyVbaApp)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostName + ")(PORT=" + portNo + ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" + srvSID + ")));"

  strCon = strDriver + strParams + strUser

  ' Open   the above connection string.
  Dim con As Object
  Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  con.ConnectionString = strCon
  con.Open

End Sub
```

Based on the above, I recommend to stay with OLEDB Provider, just update ODAC to a [latest version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).

---

If you don't want to use OLEDB at all, there are a variant with Microsoft ODBC driver(`"Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};"`) with detailed server parameters specification in `CONNECTSTRING`:

```
Const hostName = "server_host"
Const portNo = "1521"
Const srvSID = "ORASERVERSID"
Const usrID = "login"
Const usrPwd = "password"

Sub con_Microsoft_ODBC_for_Oracle()

  strDriver = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};"
  strParams = "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostName + ")(PORT=" + portNo + "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" + srvSID + ")));"
  strUser = "UID=" + usrID + ";PWD=" + usrPwd + ";"

  strCon = strDriver + strParams + strUser

  ' Open   the above connection string.
  Dim con As Object
  Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  con.ConnectionString = strCon
  con.Open

End Sub
```

Of course, this variant has its own drawbacks. At least, there are a much more probability of [support cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft's side than from side of Oracle.

Comment: I think you mixed the term `TNS`. A "TNS" string is a string like this: `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server_host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORASERVERSID)))`. File `tnsnames.ora` is used to define an **alias** for such TNS. e.g. `ORASERVERSID = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server_host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORASERVERSID)))`. There are other possibilities to define an alias, for instance by an LDAP server. In general TNS string and TNS alias are fully exchangeable.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: "In general TNS string and TNS alias are fully exchangeable" - so I mixed them :) I looked through the answer and try to be more specific with "TNS" term. Please, feel free to edit answer and correct a remaining inconsistencies. Thanks for a comment!

Comment: Remove the first paragraph, then your answer is fine. A connectionstring like `Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));Pwd=xxx;Uid=xxx` does **not** required any `tnsnames.ora` file! A `tnsnames.ora` file (or a LDAP server) is required only if you prefer to use an alias like `Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=MY_ORADB;Pwd=xxx;Uid=xxx`. The alias "MY_ORADB" is defined in the `tnsnames.ora` file. If you don't have the file you must use the full TNS string.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, but first paragraph (and question too) is about capabilities of **Oracle ODBC Driver**, not about generic Oracle client. So first paragraph are wrong only if anyone succeed with connection to Oracle with **Oracle ODBC Driver** without specifying alias name. May be something wrong with formulation of first sentence ... I changed "with" to "using", may be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.  I was trying to use MSDAORA with 64 bit.
I am using OLEDB as per the example.   Except that the oledb example doesn't populate strUser, but the next example does:
strUser = "UID=" + usrID + ";PWD=" + usrPwd + ";"
I am getting an invalid user id password, but I am sending the correct one.  This is what I am sending (I replaced the password with xxx for security reasons)
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.16.23.32)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=rmsuat)));Uid=rms;Pwd=XXX;